# What does the following expression in make file mean?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am going through a SDK's Makefile and the `<project>.elf` rule depends on the `C_OBJS`,
and the `C_OBJS` is defined as the following.

`C_OBJS = $(C_FILES:%.c=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)`

`C_FILES` is a collection of all the C files.

What I am unable to figure out is that how does the Makefile know how to convert these C files to respective OBJS before linking them to form elf(as the elf rule only links them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(C_FILES:%.c=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)` is shorthand for a `patsubst` function.   See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html).

As far as knowing how to build the `.o` files, unless you explicitly disable them,  make will use a set of predefined [implicit rules](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html#SEC95), one of which builds `.o` files from `.c` files.